# Proof of $cl(A)=A\cup A'$ with $A'$ defined as the set of all accumulation points of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $cl(A)$ be the closure of $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, the smallest closed set that contains $A$. I'd like to prove $cl(A)=A\cup A'$ with $A'$ defined as the set of all accumulation points of $A$. An accumulation point of $A$ is a point $x$ whose open balls must contain a point of $A$ distinct from $x$.

To show $cl(A)\supseteq A\cup A'$, we can consider separate cases. If $x\in A$, then $x$ must be in $cl(A)$ because the closure is itself a closed set containing $A$. If $x\notin A$, then $x$ must be an accumulation point of $A$, which enables us to show each closed set containing $A$ must contain $x$. This proves that $x\in cl(A)$.

Things have gone well so far, but I have a hard time showing that $cl(A)\subseteq A\cup A'$. Let us pick some point $x$ in $cl(A)$ that does NOT belong to $A$. How do I prove that $x$ **is** an accumulation point? Thank you.

Comment: Show that $A \cup A'$ is a closed set. Then it's automatically true (as it contains $A$) that it contains $\text{cl}(A)$ too. For that show that the complement of $A \cup A'$ is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x \in cl(A)$ and $x \notin A$. Let $B(x,\varepsilon)$ be a neighborhood of $x$. $B(x, \varepsilon)$ must contain points from $A$. Otherwise, $\mathbb{R}^n - B(x, \varepsilon)$ would be a closed set containing $A$ and hence $cl(A)$. But then $x \in \mathbb{R}^n - B(x, \varepsilon)$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $x\in A' \iff x\in \mathrm{Cl}(A\setminus \{x\})$. Thus, $A\cup A' \subseteq \mathrm{Cl}(A)$ is indeed straightforward. Conversely, if $x\in \mathrm{Int}(A)$, then we're done. Suppose $x\in \mathrm{Fr}(A)$, which implies all neighborhoods of $x$ must intersect with $A$. Assume $x$ is not an accumulation point of $A$. Then it is isolated, i.e, there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $U_x\cap A = \{x\}$, so $x\in A$.